# Rust: Error, mismatched types. Found std::result::Result

Tags: rust

I am making a system to divide two numbers, and if the second number doesn't exist, it just selects the first number. Here is the code:

```
 let new_num: f32 = match num1/num2 {
     Ok(num) => num,
     Err(error) => num1,
 };
```

However, it returns:
`Error: Mismatched types. Expected f32, found std::result::Result` 
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the code of how you're getting `num1` and `num2` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `num1/num2` is an arithmetic division. Given type `f32` for both variables `num1` and `num2`, the result of that expression has the type `f32` and not `Result`.

**Example:**

```
let num1: f32 = 2.0;
let num2: f32 = 3.0;
let new_num: f32 = num1 / num2;
```

If you want to develop logic for something that *is able to not exist*, you can use an `Option`. An `Option` is `None` if the value does not exist.

**Example of intended behaviour:**

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(2.0, divide_or_get_first(2.0, None));
    assert_eq!(5.0, divide_or_get_first(10.0, Some(2.0)));
}

fn divide_or_get_first(num1: f32, num2: Option<f32>) -> f32 {
    match num2 {
        Some(value) => {
            num1 / value
        }
        None => {
            num1
        }
    }
}
```

See:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/